# Howto use WUM for WSO2DAS - initial setup & ongoing with existing "production" installation

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Kindest,

I like the idea of what WUM does, but have been pondering how to use it properly given I have an existing production installation. I am running an older 3.1.0 installation of WSO2DAS, which is installed in

```
~/local/wso2das/
```

Where 'wso2sa' is a symlink to something like ~/local/wso2das/wso2das-3.1.0 . The reason I chose this way, was that I can change & update the versions with no change to other scripts like launchctl configurations etc. to keep it all running neatly etc.

I have installed the wum update script in ~/local/bin (which is in the PATH), and it is using ~/local/wso2products/ for its stuff. Ideally I would like to be able to run a wum product update, and then automatically push that update onto the "production" release which sits in ~/local/wso2das/ , but the howto & FAQ steps are not that descriptive in the steps required & all.

This is all running on the same system (Mac Mini), and would be awesome if someone has met a similar problem & request... and there's some more detailed examples on how to put WUM to use in such a scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are the docs https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Moving+Updates+into+Production for your use-case. Can you please pin point the steps you need more clarifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the steps and details on how to apply wum updates in a production environment on the WSO2 Admin Guidelines. Please refer the https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Moving+Updates+into+Production